# fastify not create new function when using ajv

Tags: fastify

I want to use fastify and validation/serialization and saw this

```
⚠ Security Notice
Treat the schema definition as application code. Validation and serialization features dynamically evaluate code with new Function(), which is not safe to use with user-provided schemas. See Ajv and fast-json-stringify for more details.

Regardless the $async Ajv feature is supported by Fastify, it should not be used as part of the first validation strategy. This option is used to access Databases and reading them during the validation process may lead to Denial of Service Attacks to your application. If you need to run async tasks, use Fastify's hooks instead after validation completes, such as preHandler.
```

So which is a good practice to not create everytime a new function when using validation/serializtion ?

this is now my current code

```
const PostMovieBody = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    title: { type: 'string' },
    releaseYear: { type: 'integer', minimum: 1878 },
  },
}

app.post('/movie', {
  schema: {
    // Refence the schema here
    body: PostMovieBody,
    '2xx': {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        value: { type: 'string' },
        otherValue: { type: 'boolean' }
      }
    },
  },
})
```

Do this example create everytime a new function and if yes how can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning does not imply that creating a function is a bad pattern. It explains that, given a JSON schema, a JS function is generated under the hood. The potential insecurity lies in the JSON schema provided to the framework.

Let me provide an example:

```js
const keys = await readFromExternalAndInsecureSource()

app.post('/movie', {
  schema: {
    // Reference the schema here
    body: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        validKeys: { type: 'string', enum: [...keys] },
      },
    }
  },
})
```

In this case, Fastify generates a validation function using the `keys` input, which could be potentially malicious depending on your environment.

Another example is the use of [`$async`](https://ajv.js.org/guide/async-validation.html) because it is often used to query databases and could be dangerous since the input is not yet validated at that stage.

> Does this example create a new function every time, and if yes, how can I avoid it?

Your example is fine and creates a single function for each schema (the body and the 2xx one) during startup.

I would suggest adding `maxLength` and `minLength` to strings regardless. In my Fastify book, I explain the validation and serialization process more deeply.